# Define a global query parameter to be used by any relevant route

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation, where most of the data to be fetched from the server (database) is related to a date (YYYY-MM-DD) chosen by the user.

Is it possible to define a **global "date" query parameter**, which can be used by **any relevant route**? If no value for "date" is supplied, then the server will by default return data where "date" is today.

Comment: You can use a service and inject it into all your routes through an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment by @Kitler you should use a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/applications/services/) to handle shared states. The service could be consumed by routes and controllers which needs the date. In controller you bind query param to the date value handled in service to reflect it in URL.

If you have to use this in several places you should write a [Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) to avoid repeating yourself. Dockyard has written an article [Ember Best Practices: Extend vs Mixin](https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/11/09/best-practices-extend-or-mixin) I could recommend.

Some sample code, not tested but should be enough to illustrate:

```
// app/services/settings.js
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  date: null
});

// app/route/index.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  settings: Ember.inject.service();
  model() {
    return this.store.query('post', {
      filter: { date: this.get('settings.date') }
    });
  }
});

// app/controller/index.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  date: Ember.computed.alias('settings.date'),
  queryParams: ['date'],
  settings: Ember.inject.service()
});
```